# React Input Field not allowing user Input

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty stuck with this for a while. My input field does not want to change default text, when I change my value to defaultValue, my Input field comes back as null. Here is my code:

```
interface IState {
  IPObject: IAddIP;
  ShowTimer: boolean;
  Client_IP: string;


}

interface IProps { }
export class Home extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      IPObject: {
        priority: "",
        IPList: "",
        rule: "",
        Name: "",
        Subnet: ""
      },
      ShowTimer: false,
      Client_IP: ""
    }

  }
 async componentDidMount() {
    const IPAddress = await publicIp.v4();
    this.setState({ Client_IP: IPAddress })
  }
  handleChange = () => (e: any) => {
    e.persist();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      Client_IP: e.target.value
    }));
  };
 render() {
    return (
      <>


          <label>Your IP Address</label>
          <Input placeholder="IP address" type='text' required={true} onChange={() => this.handleChange()} value={this.state.Client_IP} className="nes-input"></Input>
```

Everything seems to be correct but I do not know why I cant change the input field after it has been populated from the ComponentDidMount

Comment: Looks like you're not passing a parameter on handleChange in your onChange. You may want to check your value of e. Typically, I will include the event as a function parameter when I'm making an onChange call so it passes into the handleChange.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a function to your `onChange` parameter for `Input` component.

Bellow is fixed code:

```js
<Input 
  placeholder="IP address" 
  type='text' required={true} 
  onChange={this.handleChange()} 
  value={this.state.Client_IP} 
  className="nes-input"></Input>
```

Your `handleChange` is a curry function that gives back handler function that gets event from `Input` component. So you need to execute it directly not when the `onChange` happens.

---

**BONUS SOLUTION**

In your case you do not need to have curry function at all. Just pass the function like this:

```js
<Input 
  placeholder="IP address" 
  type='text' required={true} 
  onChange={this.handleChange} 
  value={this.state.Client_IP} 
  className="nes-input"></Input>
```

But your `handleChange` should be defined like this:

```js
handleChange = (e: any) => {
  e.persist();
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    Client_IP: e.target.value
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your input line needs to be changed to the following:

```
<Input placeholder="IP address" type='text' required={true} onChange={(e: any) => this.handleChange(e)} value={this.state.Client_IP} className="nes-input" />
```

To pass in the input event argument